# Exporting data with timezone conversion

Tags: java, spring-boot, timezone

Our users needs to export data (excel) from different timezones. The dates are UTC in database however they would like to have the data in their current timezone.

We are think about sending timezone via JWT or via header but not sure if there is a better way. Any ideas on what can be done to communicate user's timezone to backend?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring framework, you can easily get it by using `org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getTimeZone( httpServletRequest )`